# Dynamically resize relative layout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, onmeasure

I'm trying to create something that looks like this.

I can sort of get the header working, and the word cloud look-alike stuff on the right.
I'm calling it from a Fragment.

But I'm struggling to get the two column thing working.

I tried to get the width of the parent like this:

```
parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ParentLayout);
parentLayout.getMeasuredWidth()
```

this returns 0, while the parentLayout has layout_width="match_parent"

I can't seem to find tutorials/example on this type of "view", or maybe the keyword I'm using for the search is wrong.

Any input is appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!!

p.s. I tried to use onMeasure() as well, but got error "must override or implement a supertype method"

[image: Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear Layouts really can handle this type of layout just fine.  I would use an arrangement like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
         <!-- your header stuff here

        -->
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  >

            <LinearLayout android:id="left picture pane"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
                <ImageView android:layout_width="100dp"
                           android:background="@drawable/logo"
                           android:layout_height="50dp"
                           android:layout_margin="10dp"
                           />
                <ImageView android:layout_width="100dp"
                           android:background="@drawable/logo"
                           android:layout_height="50dp"
                           android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        />
                <ImageView android:layout_width="100dp"
                           android:background="@drawable/logo"
                           android:layout_height="50dp"
                           android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:text="Some Text"
                              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                              />
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="Some Text"
                          android:textColor="#80ffff"
                          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        />
                                <!-- your fancy lettering in here
                                     or you could put them in a relative layout
                                     instead of this linear one -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, it works great.
But my main concern is actually to be able to dynamically size everything with respect to one another depending on the screen size or orientation (Sorry I didn't make that clear in the question). Any suggestions? Thanks!!